# Tabs clicking work on chrome but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser, webbrowser-control, compatibility

**JavaScript code**

        $(document).ready(function(){

```
        $('#tone th:first').addClass('active');
        $('#tone tbody:not(:first)').hide();
        $("#tone th").on('click', function(event){ 
            var clicked_th = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#tone tbody').hide();
            $('.'+clicked_th+'-body').show();
            $('#tone th').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I just replace $ with jQuery. and it works correctly.